# Curve smoothing preserving peaks and valleys

Tags: r, smoothing

I want to generate a smoothed version of a set of datapoints, but preserve any local peaks or valleys (i.e. where the previous and next value are either both greater than or both less than the current value). The standard `smooth` function in R does a running median, which works great for intermediate values but chops off the peaks and valleys of the data. Here's an example which hopefully helps to explain the issue:

```
peakValleys <- runif(20);

landform <- approx(x=seq_along(peakValleys), y=peakValleys, n=200)$y;
landform <- landform + runif(200, max=0.1);

plot(landform);
points(smooth(landform), type="l", col="red");
```

[image: peak/valley with smoothing]

I'd like the red line to include any local peaks/valleys, but still look smooth (i.e. not just jumping at the peak/valley point). This is most obvious around 28, where a valley datapoint has been completely excluded.

The problem is worse if I have a larger smoothing window with the running median. Ideally, this "smoothing with peak inclusion" should work for any window size:

```
plot(landform.jitter);
points(runmed(landform.jitter, 7), type="l", col="red");
```

[image: peak/valley with smoothing window of size 7]

I care the most about the peaks/valleys, and the least about the points in between. One application of this is in finding and quantifying peaks in flow cytometry, where a small change in a peak height can mean a big difference in the estimated cell fraction. Another application is in nanopore sequencing of DNA, where peaks can be very brief, but are important to know about.

In other words, I don't mind the smoothing function missing the exact values between peaks and valleys, but it should have local maxima and minima that match the peaks.

Comment: You could use `lowess` and fiddle with `f` to shrink the proportion of points that influence the smoothing at each value.

Comment: From what I can see, lowess still chops out the peaks and valleys, unless I set f to something really small (in which case it is identical to the input data).

Comment: If you really want the line to pass through all extremes, I don't see how you do that without just drawing a line that connects them (and thus jumps at peak and valley points when they're a fair distance from their neighbors). In other words, by definition, that's not smoothing; it's just line-fitting.

Comment: You could use loess with weights.

Comment: This question would be better suited to Cross Validated, as it is not *really* about programming. However, you may consider wavelet smoothing (e.g. `wavethresh` package), where high frequency components can be utilized only for occasional "peaky" behavior and reduced elsewhere (time/frequency localization).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Confidence Based Smoothing](https://github.com/gudasergey/confsmooth). It smooths functions preserving local peaks. To distinguish peaks from noise it needs noise standard deviation (it can be scalar - common for all points, or vector).

Example usage (the code written in python):

```
from confsmooth import confsmooth
smoothed_conf = confsmooth(y, noise_level=0.03, confidence=0.99, deg=2)
```

[image: confsmooth example]

The clipping of signal at x=0 is the clipping of the noise according to the noise standard deviation `noise_level=0.03` and `confidence=0.99`. The clipped peak on the picture has error 0.07026. The probability of noise to be more than 0.07026: `erfc(error/noise_level/sqrt(2)) = 0.019`. It is greater than `1-confidence=0.01`. That's why the clipped value is treated as the noise, but not the signal.

If we use confidence=0.99 we can't call "peaks" the function values with deviation from smoothed less than `erfcinv(1-confidence)*sqrt(2)*noise_level = 0.077`. All these should be treated as the noise.

The confsmooth algorithm also checks pairs, threes, fours, etc of consecutive error values. If for example four consecutive errors are positive and more than 0.04, than their joint probability is less than 0.00766. So this four should be treated as the signal.

Comment: This looks like it's still clipping out the peaks. I want to preserve the peaks.

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain the clipping

Comment: Okay, but that explanation doesn't really help. I want to keep the peaks in, not remove them.

Comment: Then you should keep all the peaks of noise, i.e. do the linear spline interpolation. But is it right for you?